# Disable "right click release" from clicking options in the context menu

Tags: mouse, click

When I right click and the context menu pops up, I instantly move my mouse over the menu, sometimes so fast, that the release of the right-click actually clicks on the command below the cursor.

I suspect that this happen because on a Mac you can right-click and choose from the menu, or hold the right-click and then release on your options. I do not really like the second behavior, which also caused problems for me since I sometimes have deleted things or made actions that I wasn't aware of.

I am using a MacBook Pro with High Sierra and I have a normal usb mouse, I used to have the same problem though on an iMac with a magic mouse.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What kind of Mac (MacBook, iMac) do you usually use? What do you use majority of time, Trackpad, Magic Mouse or a standard USB mouse?

Comment: If you are using a Trackpad, enabling Tap to click under System Preferences → Trackpad → Point & Click may help alleviate your problem.

Comment: This behavior is by design. The click is registered when the mouse up (release) event is registered. However, the context menu is shown as soon as mouse down (press/tap) happens. I am not sure if there's any way to disable this via some setting or a 3rd-party tool.

Comment: This is causing so many unwanted actions ... it's a pity that this is not configurable

Answer (score 0):

Making the context menu show after mouse up can solve this issue.

1. Install [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).

   ```bash
   brew install --cask karabiner-elements
   ```
2. Follow [How to change mouse buttons](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/how-to/mouse-button/) to enable the mouse in Karabiner-Elements.
3. Import the Complex Modification rule: [Fix ghost select in context menu](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#fix-ghost-select-in-context-menu) and enable it.

You can read my blog [Fix Ghost Selecting in Context Menu](https://blog.willbc.com/posts/fix-ghost-selecting-in-context-menu.html#how-did-i-solve-it) for how I addressed and solved it.